# Handlebars/Node/Express Can't load files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

So I'm working on developing a Node/Express webapp for basic CRUD operations and I'm having  a hard time implementing Handlebars within the project.

When I try to use handlebars none of my stylesheets from my .hbs (previously .html) pages are loading.

Here's the file tree:

[image]

Here is the error:
[image]

And here is an example of the script import statements from

index.hbs

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And Finally here is the server.js file

```
var express     = require('express'),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
    path        = require('path'),
    mysql       = require('mysql'),
    dbconfig    = require('./config/database'),
    exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection)
connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);

var app = express();



//Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//Set static path
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//app.use('/views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views')));


app.engine('hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: false}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.set(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//app.use('/views/vendors', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/vendors')));
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/vendors'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Student", function(err, rows){
        console.log(rows);
    });


});

app.listen(80, function() {
    console.log('we are live on 80');
});
```

I tried using various static paths from other things I found on SO but wasn't able to get any of them to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: try to put "vendors" folder inside the "public" folder. adjust your code as needed after that. no static file outside the public folder will be visible, keep that on mind and imagine how those files will interact when the server gets up and running.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed my problem by adding the following line above my app.get('/'....

```
app.use("/vendors",express.static(__dirname + "/vendors"));
app.use("/build",express.static(__dirname + "/build"));
app.use("/images",express.static(__dirname + "/images"));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be possible that the problem is in the handlebars configuration, please look at a configuration like this:

```
app.engine('.hbs',exphbs({
  defaultLayout:'layouts',
  layoutsDir:path.join(app.get('views'),'layouts'),
  partialsDir:path.join(app.get('views'),'partials'),
  extname:'.hbs',
  helpers: helpers
}));
app.set('view engine','hbs');
```

maybe in yours it would be:

```
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: false, extname:'.hbs',}));
```

if you are usign `app.set(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

try to put in the public folder your styles for example the bootstrap folder, and then all you have to do is call it in this way:

```
<link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: The reason I believe this not to be the problem is because it is correctly loading the basic HTML of my index.hbs it's just not loading the styles properly. Also note I haven't even used any handlebars specific things yet. Currently it's just raw HTML CSS and some basic JS in the file.